# Code generation for compiler in Haskell

Tags: haskell, code-generation, compiler-construction

I am writing a compiler for a small imperative language. The target language is Java bytecode, and the compiler is implemented in Haskell.

I've written a frontend for the language - i.e I have a lexer, parser and typechecker. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do code generation.

I keep a data structure representing the stack of local variables. I can query this structure with the name of a local variable and get its position in the stack. This data structure is passed around as I walk the syntax tree, and variables are popped and pushed as I enter and exit new scopes.

What I having trouble figuring out is how to emit the bytecode. Emitting strings at terminals and concatenating them at higher levels seems like a poor solution, both clarity- and performance-wise.

**tl;dr** How do I emit bytecode while waling the syntax tree?

Comment: This isn't worth a full answer, and obviously involves a very different style of language, but there is [a compiler written in Haskell you may be familiar with](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/Backends) whose source code you could look at for inspiration.

Comment: Does your intermediate representation map one to one to jvm opcodes?  If not, then that's a place to start: create one or more data types to represent (a subset of) the JVM opcodes that you are targeting.  Then walk your higher-level IR and create the low-level JVM-centric IR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first project in Haskell a few months back was to write a c compiler, and what resulted was a fairly naive approach to code generation, which I'll walk through here. Please do **not** take this as an example of good design for a code generator, but rather view it as a quick and dirty (and ultimately naive) way to get something that works fairly quickly with decent performance.

I began by defining an intermediate representation LIR (Lower Intermediate Representation) which closely corresponded to my instruction set (x86_64 in my case):

```
data LIRInst = LIRRegAssignInst LIRReg LIRExpr
             | LIRRegOffAssignInst LIRReg LIRReg LIRSize LIROperand
             | LIRStoreInst LIRMemAddr LIROperand
             | LIRLoadInst LIRReg LIRMemAddr
             | LIREnterInst LIRInt
             | LIRJumpLabelInst LIRLabel
             | LIRIfInst LIRRelExpr LIRLabel LIRLabel -- false, then true
             | LIRCallInst LIRLabel LIRLabel -- method label, return label
             | LIRCalloutInst String
             | LIRRetInst [LIRLabel] String -- list of successors, and the name of the method returning from
             | LIRLabelInst LIRLabel
             deriving (Show, Eq, Typeable)
```

Next up came a monad that would handle interleaving state throughout the translation (I was blissfully unaware of our friend-the `State Monad`-at the time):

```
newtype LIRTranslator a = LIRTranslator
    { runLIR :: Namespace -> (a, Namespace) }

instance Monad LIRTranslator where
    return a = LIRTranslator (\s -> (a, s))
    m >>= f = LIRTranslator (\s ->
        let (a, s') = runLIR m s
        in runLIR (f a) s')
```

along with the state that would be 'threaded' through the various translation phases:

```
data Namespace = Namespace
    { temp         :: Int                       -- id's for new temporaries
    , labels       :: Int                       -- id's for new labels
    , scope        :: [(LIRLabel, LIRLabel)]    -- current program scope
    , encMethod    :: String                    -- current enclosing method
    , blockindex   :: [Int]                     -- index into the SymbolTree
    , successorMap :: Map.Map String [LIRLabel]
    , ivarStack    :: [(LIRReg, [CFGInst])]     -- stack of ivars (see motioned code)
    }
```

For convenience, I also specified a series of translator monadic functions, for example:

```
-- |Increment our translator's label counter
incLabel :: LIRTranslator Int
incLabel = LIRTranslator (\ns@(Namespace{ labels = l }) -> (l, ns{ labels = (l+1) }))
```

I then proceeded to recursively *pattern-match* my AST, fragment-by-fragment, resulting in **many** functions of the form:

```
translateBlock :: SymbolTree -> ASTBlock -> LIRTranslator [LIRInst]
translateBlock st (DecafBlock _ [] _) = withBlock (return [])
translateBlock st block =
    withBlock (do b <- getBlock
                  let st' = select b st
                  declarations <- mapM (translateVarDeclaration st') (blockVars block)
                  statements <- mapM (translateStm st') (blockStms block)
                  return (concat declarations ++ concat statements))
```

(for translating a block of the target language's code) or

```
-- | Given a SymbolTree, Translate a single DecafMethodStm into [LIRInst]
translateStm st (DecafMethodStm mc _) =
    do (instructions, operand) <- translateMethodCall st mc
       final <- motionCode instructions
       return final
```

(for translating a method call) or

```
translateMethodPrologue :: SymbolTree -> DecafMethod -> LIRTranslator [LIRInst]
translateMethodPrologue st (DecafMethod _ ident args _ _) =
    do let numRegVars = min (length args) 6
           regvars = map genRegVar (zip [LRDI, LRSI, LRDX, LRCX, LR8, LR9] args)
       stackvars <- mapM genStackVar (zip [1..] (drop numRegVars args))
       return (regvars ++ stackvars)
  where
    genRegVar (reg, arg) =
        LIRRegAssignInst (symVar arg st) (LIROperExpr $ LIRRegOperand reg)
    genStackVar (index, arg) =
        do let mem = LIRMemAddr LRBP Nothing ((index + 1) * 8) qword -- ^ [rbp] = old rbp; [rbp + 8] = ret address; [rbp + 16] = first stack param
                                  return $ LIRLoadInst (symVar arg st) mem
```

for an example of actually generating some LIR code. Hopefully these three examples will give you a good starting point; ultimately, you'll want to go slowly, focusing on one fragment (or intermediate type) within your AST at a time.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't done this before, you can do it in small passes:
    1) for every statement produce some byte code (with out properly addressed memory locations)
    2) after that is done, if you have looping, gotos, etc, put in the real addresses (you know them
       now that you have it all layed out)
    3) replace the memory fetches/stores with the correct locations
    4) dump it out to a JAR file

Note that this is very simplified and doesn't try to do any performance optimisation.  It will give you a functional program which will execute.  This also assumes you know the codes for the JVM (which is where I am presuming you are going to execute it.)

To start, just have a subset of the language which does sequential arithmetic statements.  This will allow you to figure out how to map variable memory locations to statements via the parse tree.  Next add some looping to get jumps to work.  Similarly add conditionals.  Finally, you can add the final parts of your language.

Comment: Just a question: Where did you get the JVM assumption? (Someone else assumed it too, and I can't find it for the life of me)

Comment: @mathepic: Second sentence of the question, "The target language is Java bytecode (...)".

Comment: @camccann Ah, okay. I must be blind :D